# how to contrl the Textbox input format without using Ajax

Tags: asp.net

How could I control the user input in the TextBox Control to be currency format $0.00 only without using Ajax.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need AJAX for that. Plain vanilla client-side JavaScript without calls to server should do it.

Comment: You should use validators, f.e. a Range- or `CompareValidator` with `Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency"`.